# Is there way to run same job for multiple nodes in jenkins through parameter input?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins and Groovy. I would like to run a job on multiple nodes by selecting them using drop-down list (parameter input using node plugin). However even though I select mutluple nodes during runtime, the job is run only for the first node in list. The sample pipeline is below.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
      node {
         label node
      }

       
    }
    
    environment {
        SERV = "${params.Service_start}"
   
  }
    stages {
            
        stage('Start Service') {
            when {
                expression {
                    params.CONFIRM_RUN
                }
            }
            steps {
                dir('service-start') {
                    bat "net start \"${env.SERV}\" /y"
                }
            }
        }

    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs ()
        }
    }
}
```

Any leads to this will be highly appreciated.

Tried to use node plugin to select multiple nodes in drop-down.

Comment: Do you want to run the same Job multiple times in different nodes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The idea is to trigger the job for selected nodes from dropdown list so that they don't require to be triggered using separate jobs. Until now, I am using node label as an input parameter for the job to be triggered for a individual node. However it's become little challenging recently since the number of nodes has increased and it's taking long time to trigger same job individually for each of them.